# My int32 var is, apparently, an object. I can´t do var += thatInteger

Tags: list, object, integer, addition, uipath

[image]
variable `curValueMonth` shows error. Apparently, is an object (can't add +) despite the fact that the list is of `int32` type. The weirdest thing is that I copied this from another workflow where it perfectly works.

I tried converting it to `int32`, but then it shows another error.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the properties panel after clicking on the for each activity, is the type assigned to int32? This activity normally defaults to object datatype upon creation and usually needs someone to manually amend to int32.